# How to search a file on database server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to get the file name of a file after uploading to my database server.
For example, I'm using Bulk Upload to import data into database. I now have multiple files in database, so I want to process a specific file by using its name.
I am looking a solution using asp.net (or asp.net core) MVC
My database is Azure and i am using asp.net core.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to save the files in a database or datastore? There is a big difference. Also Azure is a cloud service that can host a database or file storage among many other services, Azure itself is not a database.

Comment: thanks @DFord. I save a csv file to a datastore, then import data from csv to database using Azure, cloud service. Now, i am trying to get csv file from datastore using asp.net MVC(C#). If it isnt clear, i will try other way to explain it

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing has done yet. I am looking for any suggestions. It is not a task from school or job. I think about it as a problem when I study bulk upload